# Botpress webchat authetication

Tags: node.js, basic-authentication, botpress

I am trying to use authentication in BotPress web chat interface. I have seen the example here:

[BotPress Login](https://botpress.io/docs/latest/recipes/login/)

So to start with I am trying login_prompt. But how the redirection to login prompt will happen? I have tried putting all 3 things mentioned in page for basic auth but there is no redirection happening to login prompt.

Comment: Could you post the code you tried and the errors you get?

Answer (score 1):

If you did everything they say in the manual only you need to activate the login.

In orden to do this you need to edit the file `botfile.js` and change the value of `login.enabled` to true

```
/*
  Access control of admin panel
*/
login: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // true
    useCloud: process.env.BOTPRESS_CLOUD_ENABLED,
    tokenExpiry: '6 hours',
    password: process.env.BOTPRESS_PASSWORD || 'password',
    maxAttempts: 3,
    resetAfter: 10 * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes
},
```

Or start your application in production mode.

To set an environment variable in Windows:

```
SET NODE_ENV=production
```

on Linux:

```
export NODE_ENV=production
```